1000th generation, and creating the world out of Rachamim

I recently saw in a (Chassidic) sefer that the concept of "Hashem intended to make the world out of justice, but saw that it wouldn't last, so made it out of mercy" (Rashi on Bereshit) means that Hashem didn't intend to send us Tzaddikim, but saw that we needed them, so thus He verily did.

I also know of the concept of the 974 generations that were not created because they would not accept the Torah. Adam was different because one his offshoots would indeed accept it. They did so in the 26th generation since Adam, so the total is 1000 generations.


My question is: are there any sources that connect these two ideas? Specifically, the Tzaddikim approach was only utilised starting from Adam, and 975th generation? The argument being that Hashem actually did give His creations a chance with the din approach, but set a time limit on that, and invoked the rachamim approach in time to make sure no more than 1000 generations will go by without accepting Torah?

When u say din, I am pretty sure u r referring to the sefirah of gevurah. When I learnt this, I am 99.99% sure that HaShem didn't even give a chance with the din approach. This is cause in a world with that amount of din, there would be no way you can reveal Godliness. For example, in a world with so much din, u would have a miracle of finding $10,000 in the basement of a house u just bought. But, it will be very hard for u to come to the conclusion that G_d made a miracle for u to find that money. This is cause u would be living in a world with way too much din which conceals Godliness. .
